# while loop, windows form exercise c#

Tags: c#

**Updated**
Thank you for the replies. Much appreciated. I do apologize for my noob status. This is my first assignment in c#, and my first c# class. Without much previous programming experience at all. So a lot of these concepts are being first introduced. This is what I have done to complete the first section of the assignment.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool oddNum(double value)
    {
        return value % 2 != 0;
    }
    public bool IsPrime(int n)
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Where(x => n % x == 0).SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, n });
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool evenNum(double value)
    {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double start = Double.Parse(txtStart.Text);
        double end = Double.Parse(txtEnd.Text);
        double oddCount = 0;
        double evenCount = 0;
        double evenSum = 0;
        double oddSum = 0;
        double totalSum = 0;
        double avrgNum = 0;
        double avrgSum = 0;
        double productNum = 1;         



        while (start <= end)
        {

            if (oddNum(start))
            {
                oddSum += start;
                oddCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                evenSum += start;
                evenCount++;
            }
            totalSum += start;
            productNum *= start;
            avrgNum = totalSum / end;
            avrgSum = avrgNum / totalSum;
            start++;
         }
        string info = ("Number of odd numbers: " + oddCount.ToString() + "\n" + "Number of even numbers: " + evenCount.ToString() + "\n" + "Sum of odd numbers: " + oddSum.ToString() + "\n" +
                        "Sum of even numbers: " + evenSum.ToString() + "\n" + "Sum of all numbers: " + totalSum.ToString() + "\n" + "Product of all numbers: " + productNum.ToString() + "\n" +
                         "Average: " + avrgNum.ToString("F2") + "\n" + "Average / Sum of all numbers: " + avrgSum.ToString("F2"));
        lblOutput.Text = info;


    }

    private void btnPrime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int start = Convert.ToInt32(txtStart.Text);
        if (IsPrime(start))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The start number is prime.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The start number is not prime.");
        }
    }
 }
```

}

**____________**

"Create a Windows Forms Application that performs some while loops, if-else statements and double
type calculations."

Comment: The two blocks of code you provided are methods that return either a true or a false value. They should be contained within a class, which I'm assuming they are if you created a new Windows Forms project. Did you assign event handlers to your two buttons? The methods you have now can be called from within the loop but should not (and cannot) be contained within it.

Comment: With all due respect, you should at least understand the basics of the language before asking questions.  This sort of information is literally **everywhere**, from the internet to textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are looping through your while loop, you should be checking if the number is odd or even, by calling one of your methods (don't really need both). Something like this:

```
while (startingNumber != endingNumber)
{
    if (oddNum(startingNumber))
        oddNumbersLabel.Text += " " + startingNumber;
    else
        evenNumbersLabel.Text += " " + startingNumber;

    startingNumber += incrementValue;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i updated my question above to show more information. I need to print out the sum of the odd and even numbers within the start and end number listed. And output that into my output label with the rest of the information like the average of the numbers. Link for the assignment is posted in my question too.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Yes it is a school assignment to help prep us for the coming test. Most our exercises leading up to this where just creating a windows console application.

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? As far as I can tell, you've got the sum part of the even and odd numbers correct. Where are you stuck?

Comment: how would i output that to my lblOutput.Text to see if the loop is currently working correctly. would i have my Output statement just outside the while-loop? is that what your first reply was doing? where  you had oddNumbersLabel.Text, setup print the information?

Comment: Exactly, you should be outputting all the even and odd number sum after the while loop finished. `lblOutput.Text = string.Format("Even numbers sum: {0}\n Odd numbers sum: {1}", evenSum, oddSum)`

Comment: I started to create a string called info that i would output with the label. like string info = ("Number of odd numbers: " + oddCount.ToString() + "\n" + "Number of even numbers: " + evenCount.ToString() + "\n"    ect.     and   lblOutput.Text = info;  to output it. But your update using the string.Format seems like a better way of doing it. The problem i ran into, was my counters and calculations of the sum for the odd and even numbers, does not count the odd or even number listed in the text input. so 1-3 i counts as only one of those numbers as odd. I think its only including the start #.

Comment: If you want to include the end number in your while loop, then you should change the while loop's condition to: `while (start <= end)`